# Generate and move thumbnails recursively

Tags: bash, find, imagemagick, thumbnails

I want a bash script which does the following:

- Find pictures (jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG) recursively from current directory downwards
- Generate a thumbnail with imagemagick's convert
- Move thumbnail to other directory

My current script looks like this:

```
for f in `find . -type f -iname "*.jpg"`
  do
  convert ./"$f" -resize 800x800\> ./"${f%.jpg}_thumb.jpg"
  mv ./"${f%.jpg}_thumb.jpg" /home/user/thumbs/
done
```

It doesn't convert files (or folders with all content) which have spaces/special characters. I tried with `print0` but it didn't help.

Comment: [Don't loop over `find`'s output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use more advanced options like [`-set`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#set) combined with [*percent escapes*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) (namely `%t` to extract the filename without directory or extension) to do the resize, rename and move of each file with a single `convert` invocation:

```
find . -type f -iname \*.jpg -exec convert {} -resize 800x800\> \
-set filename:name '%t' '/home/user/thumbs/%[filename:name]_thumb.jpg' \;
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't iterate over the output of `find`.
The problem you are experiencing is a typical consequence of that.

Your example is a bit tricky due to the file renaming.
One not very efficient but safe way to do it is with the `-exec` option of `find`, and an additional `sh` per each file, like this:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec sh -c 'echo convert "$1" -resize 800x800\> /home/user/thumbs/"${1%.jpg}_thumb.jpg"' -- {} \;
```

If you didn't mind using the same name (with `.jpg` suffix instead of `_thumb.jpg`), then this simple form would work, and be much more efficient:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec echo convert "{}" -resize 800x800\> /home/user/thumbs/"{}" \;
```

I added `echo` statements there to check the output before executing the commands. Remove them if the output looks good.

Comment: @janos, phk and don_crissti:   I just accepted the answer from don, but I also upvoted the answers which are working. Thanks for your support guys, you had very interesting/educational answers to my first question on this site :)

Answer (score 2):

In your solution the file names got split on the default `$IFS` which includes spaces.

Try the following:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do

    convert ./"$f" -resize 800x800\> ./"${f%.jpg}_thumb.jpg"
    mv ./"${f%.jpg}_thumb.jpg" /home/user/thumbs/

done < <(find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0)
```

The `find` prints the file names separated by null bytes (`\0`) and using `-d ''` you set the delimiter of `read` to the same.

Comment: @don_crissti There is a second meaning to `-format` but I misunderstood it. There is also `-set` but I don't get its syntax: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes

I don't think I will invest any more time into this.

Comment: @don_crissti I would feed it all the files as parameters through `find […] -exec mogrify […] {} +` but apparently it's a bad idea for another reason: _"However all three images [in the example] are read into memory, and then modified by the one command. This is not a recommended solution for a number of large images, or very large numbers of images, due to the posibilty [sic] of reaching memory limits and thus going to disk swapping (thrashing)."_ (from the link posted in my previous comment). Maybe the possibility of such cases is also smth. worth mentioning in your long overview post.

Comment: @phk Your snipped worked too, however I don't know which answer is the better/more efficient one.